# Oracle PL/SQL: Error returned without value on function

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

I'm trying to create a function that will compute for factorial but  it returns an error when I do a `SELECT FACTORIAL('1') FROM DUAL;`

It returns the heinous `error:function returned without value`. I tried adding an exception but it seems that it doesn't work either. Care to help?

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FACTORIAL(p_factorial INTEGER) 
      RETURN NUMBER
       AS var_fnumber number(2);
       ctr number(2);
       var_contain number(2) := 1;
    BEGIN
       FOR ctr in 1..p_factorial 
    LOOP
      BEGIN
          var_contain := var_contain * ctr;
          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(var_contain);
      EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
          RETURN 0;
      END;
    END LOOP;

  END; --FACTORIAL;
  /
```

Comment: Add `RETURN VAR_CONTAIN;` immediately before `END; --FACTORIAL;`. Share and enjoy.

Comment: Please remember, a `NUMBER` shoukd never be stored as a `STRING`. Sooner or later, you would find it to be a performance issue. Always, as in always, avoid implicit data conversions.

Answer (score 2):

You MUST return something in a function.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2    FUNCTION FACTORIAL(
  3        p_factorial INTEGER)
  4      RETURN NUMBER
  5    AS
  6      var_fnumber NUMBER(2);
  7      ctr         NUMBER(2);
  8      var_contain NUMBER(2) := 1;
  9    BEGIN
 10      FOR ctr IN 1..p_factorial
 11      LOOP
 12        BEGIN
 13          var_contain := var_contain * ctr;
 14        END;
 15      END LOOP;
 16      RETURN var_contain;
 17    END;
 18    /

Function created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT factorial(2) FROM dual
  2  /

FACTORIAL(2)
------------
           2
```

For more details, read http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/05/01/ora-06503-plsql-function-returned-without-value/

Answer (score 0):

modified your code try this:

```
create or replace
FUNCTION FACTORIAL(p_factorial INTEGER) 
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
var_contain varchar2(50):= 1;
BEGIN
FOR ctr in 1..p_factorial 
LOOP
var_contain := var_contain * ctr;
END LOOP;
EXCEPTION 
WHEN OTHERS THEN
RETURN O;
return var_contain;
```

Comment: Why `VARCHAR2 for `NUMBER`? The factorial of a number returns a number, isn't it? And how this add to the answer already provided?

Comment: Try to get a factorial for a number that has a large factorial value.U ll get precision error.so its better to use something like varchar in these cases

Comment: You're implicitly converting the character to a number for the multiplication so it makes no sense to store it in a character at all. Any errors you think you're avoiding will still hit you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FACTORIAL(p_factorial INTEGER) 
   RETURN NUMBER
   AS var_fnumber number;
      ctr number;
      var_contain number := 1;
   BEGIN
      FOR ctr in 1..p_factorial 
        LOOP
          BEGIN
              var_contain := var_contain * ctr;
          EXCEPTION
              WHEN OTHERS THEN
              RETURN 0;
          RETURN var_contain;
          END;
        END LOOP;
RETURN var_contain;    
END; --FACTORIAL;
/
```

Was gonna say that I found it. Thank you for the answers.

As for the reason why I used varchar2, I wasn't finalizing it yet.